# Return values from python script to R and storing those values in `R`

Tags: python, r

Basically,

I managed to execute a python script within `R`. However, I have no idea how to return those values from the python script to `R` and store those values in `R`, especially when I have multiple functions in the python script.

What should I add to the python script to make this process possible ?

note: Suppose I pass in the arguments `python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3` from R to python at the beginning.

This the `test.py` I have written below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys


jd = sys.argv
def testing(jd):
    print 'Number of arguments:', len(jd), 'arguments.'
    print 'Argument List:', str(jd)
    return jd

def testing2():
    return 123123


testing(jd)
testing2()
```

Comment: Can you add the R code you use to call this?

Comment: Is the R code relevant ?

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear what you want. Capturing simple output is easy:

```
a = system('python -c "print \\"test\\""', intern = TRUE)
a
#[1] "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking out R/SPlus here: http://www.omegahat.org/RSPython/

It supports calling Python scripts and functions in modules etc. and returns values as an SEXP which is an R generic datatype.